# How can I automatically run some code when my gem is activated?

Tags: ruby, plugins, rubygems, monkeypatching

I created a gem that is essentially a plugin/extension to an existing Ruby app.  The app has some consideration for this using bundler; it automatically executes `Bundle.require :misc` when starting up.

I've added my Gem to the `:misc` group in the `Gemfile` and my gem is getting added to the load path as expected.  The challenge is that in order for my extension to work correctly I need to monkey patch some existing classes.

All my monkey patch code is contained in a ruby file in the gem (let's say `lib/mygem/patch.rb`).  If I manually edit the source of the base app to call `require 'mygem/patch'` after the existing line for `Bundle.require :misc` then everything works great.  However that is sloppy and requires editing the installed gem for the base app every time I reinstall gems or move to a new machine.

```
# Currently I can load my gem and execute the monkey patch in 2 lines
gem 'mygem'
require 'mygem/patch'

# Or with bundler (mygem is in the :misc group)
Bundle.require :misc
require 'mygem/patch'

# I want to achieve the same result in only one line
gem 'mygem'

# or
Bundle.require :misc
```

I want to automatically run some code from inside my extension gem whenever it is activated from the base application, without having to manually require the file.  The solution should work both when the gem is individually activated with a `gem 'mygem'` statement, or as part of a bundle group as in `Bundle.require :misc`.

Is this possible?  Is there a better pattern to address monkey-patching from within a "plugin/extension" gem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear when you want your code to run. Do you want it to run when Ruby starts the program, or when Bundler builds the list of gems for an app?

If you're talking about when Ruby loads the code to run it...

Ruby supports `BEGIN {...}` and `END {...}` blocks that get run before variables are initialized. They're run as they're seen, but, obviously, `END {...}` would run at the end of the program, just prior to the interpreter exiting.

See ["Programming Ruby"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UA):

> BEGIN and END Blocks
>
> Every Ruby source file can declare blocks of code to be run as the file is being loaded (the BEGIN blocks) and after the program has finished executing (the END blocks).

```
BEGIN {
  begin code
}


END {
  end code
}
```

> A program may include multiple BEGIN and END blocks. BEGIN blocks are executed in the order they are encountered. END blocks are executed in reverse order.

You can also add code to a gem, class, or module file, that will get run as the file is loaded, to initialize variables/constants that get dynamically defined. There's no special requirement for that, just don't put it in a `class` or `def`. Code at the main level will run as expected, including if it's in a module -- it's that "main level" part that is important.

Do any of these carefully because you don't want to impact the load or exit time of the gem, adversely affecting the program.

Also, be very careful about monkey-patching existing classes in Ruby. If you change the functionality of an existing method, you can badly break a user's Ruby app. If you add a method name that conflicts with one the user has defined then the same situation can occur too, and, in either case, that can be difficult to track down and fix.

---

To elaborate:

When Ruby requires a class or module file, it loads it, then runs the code it finds in there. Any classes or constants get initialized and any code at the main level runs. At the bottom of the file Ruby will move on to the next "require" statement.

Consider a file containing:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "Inside Foo.new()"
  end
end
```

Running that will return nothing, nor will anything be executed. The class will be parsed, but since nothing invokes `Foo.new` we don't even see the output. That's why we don't embed code we want to run automatically inside the class, because it won't be run unless something explicitly calls it. Requiring it will have the same result.

Changing the code to the following and running it outputs "Inside Foo.new()":

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "Inside Foo.new()"
  end
end

Foo.new()
# >> Inside Foo.new()
```

That's explicitly calling the class initializer.

If the first code was required by another file, when it's run nothing will happen because the class isn't invoked until something in the requiring code or a subsequently loaded file tells Ruby to run it. Having the class initializer run results in:

```
Inside Foo.new()
```

In any case, the method or class definition wouldn't be run until it's invoked by `foo` or `Foo.new()`, which then causes the new instance to be defined, allowing the initializer to run.

If the OP wants to run something in his own gem, putting it inside a `def` or `class` will hide it. It's got to be at the main level for Ruby to run it. And, again, this assumes the question is about code running when Ruby loads the script, and NOT about code Rubygems or Bundler can run at installation time.

Comment: The Cowardly Lion would like you to elaborate on, "..just don't put it in a class or module..", but is too afraid to ask.

Comment: "The Cowardly Lion"? There is more than one character called "Tin Man" in the world of literature and cinema. To elaborate on what I said I guess I'll have to add some sample code to explain.

Comment: CL says his question was a general one, about code run when a script is loaded, and points out that you can invoke class methods while a class is being constructed (e.g., `class Cat; def self.speak; p "Meow"; end; speak; end => "Meow"`).

Comment: @theTinMan My question is rubygems specific, this is all general ruby information and does not address it at all.  I want to know how to trigger code to run when my gem is activated/loaded by Rubygems or Bundler.  Do you understand? If needed I can reframe the question.

Comment: I added a more concrete example, hope that clarifies what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't really a supported feature.

However, as the `lib` directory of your gem is added to the load path, you can piggyback on other requires by adding a file of the same name in your `lib` directory.

As an example, if the class that you're monkeypatching relies on another class that requires `erb`, then create a file `lib/erb.rb`. As `erb` is in the standard library, your `erb.rb` file will be required instead, because gems appear in the load path before the standard library.

You need to make sure that you require the original file as well. So you could set the contents of `erb.rb` to the following:

```
filename = File.basename(__FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.map { |path|
  Dir.glob("#{path}/*#{filename}").map { |file|    
    require file unless file.include? GEM_NAME
  }
}

puts 'Custom file within gem was required'
```

Then build/reinstall your gem. When the hijacked `require` is called:

```
$ bundle exec irb
2.0.0 :001 > require 'erb'
Custom file within gem was required
 => true
```

This approach can only work when there is a `require` that you can hijack before your patch needs to take effect (and for a file that exists in the load path after your own gem).